# Neo4j - Project graph from Neo4j with GraphDataScience

Tags: graph, neo4j, syntax, project

So I have a graph of nodes -- "Papers" and relationships -- "Citations".
Nodes have properties: "x", a list with 0/1 entries corresponding to whether a word is present in the paper or not, and "y" an integer label (one of the classes from 0-6).

I want to project the graph from Neo4j using GraphDataScience.
I've been using this [documentation](https://console.neo4j.io/#getting-started-gds) and I indeed managed to project the nodes and vertices of the graph:

## Code

```
from graphdatascience import GraphDataScience

AURA_CONNECTION_URI = "neo4j+s://xxxx.databases.neo4j.io"
AURA_USERNAME = "neo4j"
AURA_PASSWORD = "my_code:)"

# Client instantiation
gds = GraphDataScience(
    AURA_CONNECTION_URI,
    auth=(AURA_USERNAME, AURA_PASSWORD),
    aura_ds=True
)

#Shorthand projection --works
shorthand_graph, result = gds.graph.project(
    "short-example-graph",
    ["Paper"],
    ["Citation"]
)
```

When I do print(result) it shows

nodeProjection              {'Paper': {'label': 'Paper', 'properties': {}}}
relationshipProjection    {'Citation': {'orientation': 'NATURAL', 'aggre...
graphName                                               short-example-graph
nodeCount                                                              2708
relationshipCount                                                     10556
projectMillis                                                            34
Name: 0, dtype: object

However, no properties of the nodes are projected. I then use the extended syntax as described in the documentation:

```
# Project a graph using the extended syntax
extended_form_graph, result = gds.graph.project(
    "Long-form-example-graph",
    {'Paper': {properties: "x"}},
    "Citation"
)

print(result)
```

#Errors
I get the error:
NameError: name 'properties' is not defined

I tried various variations of this, with or without " ", but none have worked so far (also documentation is very confusing because one of the docs always uses " " and in another place I did not see " ").

Also, note that all my properties are integers in the Neo4j db (in AuraDS), as I used to have the error that String properties are not supported.

Some clarification on the correct way of projecting node features (aka properties) would be very useful.

thank you,
Dina

Answer (score 0):

The keys in the Python dictionaries that you use with the GraphDataScience library should be enclosed in quotation marks. This is different from Cypher syntax, where map keys are not enclosed with quotation marks.

This should work for you.

```
extended_form_graph, result = gds.graph.project(
    "Long-form-example-graph",
    {'Paper': {"properties": "x"}},
    "Citation"
)
```

Best wishes,

Nathan

Comment: I tried this before. I get the following error:ClientError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed} {message: Failed to invoke procedure `gds.graph.project`: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Loading of values of type String is currently not supported}

Comment: Does the projection work for you in Neo4j browser? `call gds.graph.project(
    "Long-form-example-graph",
    {Paper: {properties: "x"}},
    "Citation"
)`

Comment: You might also try the this in Python, but I expect it to give you the same error you got with my previous suggestion. `extended_form_graph, result = gds.graph.project("Long-form-example-graph", "Paper", "Citation", nodeProperties = "x")`

Comment: Yep, it gives me the same error... :-(

Comment: And also in the Neo4j browser as well!! I get: Failed to invoke procedure `gds.graph.project`: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Loading of values of type String is currently not supported

Comment: I have edited the properties of the nodes in Neo4j (when I imported them) to be integers... so I am not sure how to solve this. Any idea why I get this error?

Comment: Does apoc.meta.nodeTypeProperties tell you that x is a string? https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.meta/apoc.meta.nodeTypeProperties/

Comment: Yeah, it's weird... when I do that in the neo4j browser, x appears as "String" which is maybe understandable, because x is a vector of integers and there is no type for vector of integers, so setting "integer" in the properties section may not work (and that makes sense). But y appears as ["Long", "String"], which is definitely weird.

Comment: A row in my .csv file is: header: id,x,y,train,valid,test

Comment: and then the first row 0, 0 0 0 1 0 ......... 0, 3, 1, 0, 0

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening with the import, but you might try this: `MATCH (p:Paper) with split(x, ",") as splitX set p.intX = [val in splitX | toInteger(val)]`. That would create a new property called intX instead of overwriting the old x property just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: You might also try `MATCH (p:Paper) where p.y <> toInteger(p.y) RETURN p, p.y` to find the Paper nodes that have string values for y.

Comment: I didn't do anything with the y feature, just updated gds (?)... with x, I initially had it String then ran in Neo4j Browser: MATCH (p:Paper) SET p.intX = [val in split(p.x, " ") | toInteger(val)] and it worked fine to project from there. Many many thanks.